# Receive data from the Java application (Server-Client) and display them as notifications in the Android application

Tags: java, android

My University project is (version manager) like git

It consists of three parts

1 - **Server** (Java Application)

2 - **Client** (Java Application) can Modification on Project

3 - **Client-Notification** (Android Application)

Client (Java Application) can Create Project and Add contributor to his Project
**exactly** like Git/GitHub and any Contributor Can Modification on Project

Client-Notification (Android Application) just work for Receive Data from Server

example: contributor (A) **edited** the project (Add Commit,Add Branch) here Server (Java Application) will send Data To Client Notification (Android Application) and must Display like (Notification in android)

I need a way to synchronize the application of the android and the server where it can get events synchronously **locally**

I used ....

ServerSocket : in Server

Socket : Client (Java Application) , (Android Application)

every Client Have Account (Login) , Account for (Java, Android Clients) has same Username and Password for each Client

Answer (score 0):

Try [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/) to listen to data changes in realtime.

> The Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted NoSQL database that
>   lets you store and sync data between your users in realtime.

and, you can use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to send notifications